# Copying the Apache Spark installation folder to another system will work properly?

Tags: apache-spark

I am using Apache Spark. Working in cluster properly with 3 machines. Now I want to install Spark on another 3 machines.

**What I did:** I tried to just copy the folder of Spark, which I am using currently.

**Problem:** ./bin/spark-shell and all other spark commands are not working and throwing error **'No Such Command'**

**Question:** 1. Why it is not working?

2. Is it possible that I just build Spark installation for 1 machine and then from that installation I can distribute it to other machines?

I am using Ubuntu.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We were looking into problem and found that **Spark Installation Folder** , which was copied, having the **.sh** files but was not executable. We just make the files executable and now spark is running.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, It would work but should ensure that you have set all the environment variables required for spark to work.

like SPARK_HOME, WEBUI_PORT etc...

also use hadoop integrated spark build which comes with the supported versions of hadoop.

Comment: I have configured the bash accordingly.. but still not working.. haddop never comes in picture for us because we aren't using it at all..